# how to avoid one number when the number is 00 in swift 4?

Tags: swift, time, seconds

I used the method for current time in my app But the problem is that when the 0 is behind a number the app won't print that like 10:23:4 as you see when the second is 04 the app won't print 04 and print 4 - I know that I can handle this with if else method But I want to know is it possible to fix that in codes or the only way is that? i know that I can use for loop But I want to use one line code to fix that because if use for loop I need to use that for hour and minutes too!

here is my codes

```
let date = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
    let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
    let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: date)

    print("Time=\(hour):\(minutes):\(seconds)")
```

Comment: Please, just use a DateFormatter https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter

Comment: @Wukerplank exactly! Why are you not using a DateFormatter for this?

Comment: I know that Date Formatter is another way But I wanted to know how to use this and you can see the answer here below

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi DateFormatter is not "another way", it is the correct way to display date/time ;-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this!

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
let hourString = String.init(format: " %02d:%02d:%02d", hour,minutes,seconds)
print(hourString)
```

Comment: this method printed this ( 12:27: 0)
so now there is space but still there is no 0

Comment: I updated my answer @SaeedRahmatolahi

Comment: thanks a lot this worked for me But please change print("(hourString)") to print(hourString) to print time

Comment: This is a date. Use a DateFormatter.

Comment: so I converted the hour - minute and second to persian format But the problem is that this method here will not work in that format I will ask another question please check that

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi, if you would used `DateFormatter`, as several people already suggested you wouldn't have to create any new questions about hack-y ways to solve you problems.

Comment: please write answer DateFormatter and I will vote that answer